# Load FirebaseUser info gives null value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

In showdata method witch load FirebaseUser info I have null value for uInfo , I run the app and signed in with User_02 , debugging show that  : 
ds.getChild(userId )  reach to the right user  who signed in and loaded with right key , but when try to get value from UserInformations.class gives me NullPointerException  ,so what the mistake in the coade ?

I not that ds have key and value for  User_01 . is that normal ?

```
public class AddToDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "AddToDatabase";
    private ListView userInfolist ;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    String userId;
    UserInformations uInfo =new UserInformations();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_to_database);
        userInfolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userInfolist);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userId = user.getUid();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    toastMassege(" You are successfly signed in with " + user.getEmail());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    toastMassege(" You are successfly signed out ");
                }
            }
        };

        // Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 showData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value

            }
        });
    }

      private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


            uInfo.setName(ds.child(userId).getValue(UserInformations.class).getName());            // set the name
            uInfo.setEmail(ds.child(userId).getValue(UserInformations.class).getEmail());          // set the Email
            uInfo.setPhone_num(ds.child(userId).getValue(UserInformations.class).getPhone_num());  // set the PhonNum

            ArrayList<String> arrayList =new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add(uInfo.getName());
            arrayList.add(uInfo.getEmail());
            arrayList.add(uInfo.getPhone_num());
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
            userInfolist.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
    private void toastMassege(String massege) {
        Toast.makeText(this, massege, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**UserInformation.java**

```
class UserInformations {

    private String Email,Name,Phone_num ;

    UserInformations() {
    }

    String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    void setEmail(String email) {
        this.Email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    String getPhone_num() {
        return Phone_num;
    }

    void setPhone_num(String phone_num) {
        this.Phone_num = phone_num;
    }

}
```

[image: this is screen shot for debugging and database structure]

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?

Comment: No didn't , I tried Answer 1 but it didn't work , gives the same error and uInfo still have null value , I signed in with User_03 , userId is correct Id , but ds have User_01 key and values , then ds.getValue(UserInformations.class).getName() == User_01 name

Comment: I already post answer of mine below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your variables in `UserInformations` from **private** to **public**.

```
class UserInformations {

    public String Email,Name,Phone_num ;

}
```

Second, you have to change your Firebase path from `Phone number` to `Phone_num`. Why? Well, that's because you are declaring `String Phone_num` inside the `UserInformation`.

**Your current JSON:**

```
{
  "uid001": {
    "Email": "user01@gmail.com",
    "Name": "user01",
    "Phone number": "0123456789"
  },
  "uid002": {
    "Email": "user02@gmail.com",
    "Name": "user02",
    "Phone number": "0123456789"
  },
}
```

**Changed to below JSON:**

```
{
  "uid001": {
    "Email": "user01@gmail.com",
    "Name": "user01",
    "Phone_num": "0123456789"
  },
  "uid002": {
    "Email": "user02@gmail.com",
    "Name": "user02",
    "Phone_num": "0123456789"
  },
}
```

Comment: it gives me error : com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: name

Comment: That means the previous error is solved. Now you have another error. Hmm. Can you include it in the question. The full trace of error

Comment: I asked anther ques about this project yesterday and have no answer , can you take a look  of it ??<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425921/arraylist-always-loaded-with-user-info-from-firebase-database-regardless-of-whic>

Answer (score 0):

When you used `for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())` the `ds` already have the data of the child which is the user node no need for `child(userId)` do it directly :

```
uInfo.setName(ds.child("name").getValue()); 
uInfo.setEmail(ds.child("email").getValue());
uInfo.setPhone_num(ds.child("phone_num").getValue());
```

Comment: it didn't work , gives the same error and     uInfo  still have null value , I signed in with User_03 ,      userId is correct Id , but     ds have User_01 key and values , then     ds.getValue(UserInformations.class).getName()  == User_01 name ,

Comment: I'm thankful for your effort but it did not work and give the same error .